# add key value pairs in program options

Tags: c++, dictionary, command-line, boost-program-options

I need to load a map inside my program, with an integer key and a string value, like this:

```
1, oil
2, car
5, house
```

I want to load them using `boost::program_options`. I can see in the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html) that I can load a vector from options with a syntax like this one:

```
int opt;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("optimization", po::value<int>(&opt)->default_value(10), "optimization level")
    ("include-path,I", po::value< vector<string> >(), "include path")
    ("input-file", po::value< vector<string> >(), "input file");
```

then I can use `program --input-file file1, --input-file file2` in order to create a vector with `file1` and `file2`. What's the best way to implement a map from program options?

I can use for example a string and then splitting string in order to obtain values, like `program --pair "1, oil" --pair "2, car" --pair "5, house"`, or I can separate them using `program --key 1 --value oil --key 2 --value car --key 5 --value car`.

I want to use something that can be written easily from both command line and configuration file. Which method is the best one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use for example a string and then splitting string in order to obtain values, like `program --pair "1, oil" --pair "2, car" --pair "5, house"` ...

I'd stick with the 1st option and read the `std::vector<std::string>` vector of strings. Afterwards you go through the natively parsed vector, split up the strings and fill your map.

> ... or I can separate them using program --key 1 --value oil --key 2 --value car --key 5 --value car

I'm not sure this way would preserve the strong ordering you need.

Comment: Ok this was my original idea. If this is the 'standard' way to use options in order to pass a map then I'll use it. thanks.

Comment: @Jepessen There's not really a _standard way_ but it's making your interface more clear for users.